# How do you use chmod inside a shell script

Tags: shell, chmod

So this is in a shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
trialName= "trial.txt"

chmod a+rwx $trialName
```

That doesn't really work. I am trying to add single quote/double quotes around `$trialName` but that doesn't work either. Any way I can do that?

Comment: Perhaps it was my mistake, however, the variable declaration is incorrect for bash, also, try running the script with `-x` option and you should see where it fails.

Comment: The line `trialName= "trial.txt"` is legal, but it sets the variable `$trialName` to the empty string and then tries to execute the command `trial.txt`. You should have gotten an error message like `trial.txt: command not found` -- and you *really* should have told us that. Telling is "That doesn't really work" is less helpful than it could be.

Comment: SUre, sorry about that! Will give all the adequate info from next time on when I ask questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to remove the space after the `=`:

```
trialName="trial.txt" # note the absence of the space between '=' and '"'
chmod a+rwx "$trialName"
```

Comment: @Joshi Super.  Feel free to accept this answer by clicking the checkmark on the left if it helped you.  That gives both you and me rep, and helps future visitors know what fixed your problem. (Note that you must wait until ten minutes have past since your initial posting to accept an answer.)

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/bin/bash
TRIALNAME="trial.txt"

chmod a+rwx $TRIALNAME
```

Does it work? You can't have whitespace between the `=`